# How spring-cloud-stream-rabbit-binder works when RabbitMQ disk or memory alarm is activated?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

**Versions:**

Spring-cloud-stream-starter-rabbit --> 2.1.0.RELEASE

RabbitMQ --> 3.7.7

Erlang --> 21.1

---

**(1)**  I have created a sample [mq-publisher-demo](https://github.com/GhodasaraChetan/mq-publisher-demo) & [mq-subscriber-demo](https://github.com/GhodasaraChetan/mq-subscriber-demo) repositories on github for reference.

[image]

> **When Memory Alarm was activated**
>
> > **Publisher**: was able to publish messages.
> >
> > **Subscriber**: seems like, the subscriber was receiving messages **in batch** with few delays.
>
> **When Disk Alarm was activated**
>
> > **Publisher**: was able to publish messages.
> >
> > **Subscriber**: seems like, the subscriber was not receiving messages while Disk Alarm was activated. but once the alarm was deactivated, **all messages** were received by the subscriber.

Are the messages getting buffered somewhere?

Is this the expected behavior? 
(because I was expecting RabbitMQ will stop receiving messages from the publisher and the subscriber will never get any subsequent messages once any of the alarms are activated.)

**(2)** [Spring Cloud Stream document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_binder_overview) says below. 
Does it mean the above behaviour? (avoiding deadlock & keep publisher publishing the messages)

> Starting with version 2.0, the RabbitMessageChannelBinder sets the RabbitTemplate.userPublisherConnection property to true so that the non-transactional producers avoid deadlocks on consumers, which can happen if cached connections are blocked because of a memory alarm on the broker.

**(3)** Do we have something similar for `Disk alarm` also to avoid deadlocks?

**(4)** If the producer's message will not be accepted by RabbitMQ, then is it possible to throw specific exception to the publisher from spring-cloud-stream (saying alarms are activated and message publish failed)?

I'm kind of new about these alarms in spring-cloud-stream, please help me to understand clearly. Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the messages getting buffered somewhere?

Yes, when resource alarm is set, messages will be published into network buffers.

- Tiny messages will take some time to fill up Network buffer and then
  block publishers.
- Less network buffer size will block publishers
  soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to ask questions about the behavior of RabbitMQ itself (and the Java client that Spring uses) on the rabbitmq-users Google group; that's where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out.

> (2) Spring Cloud Stream document says below. Does it mean the above behaviour?

That change was made so that if producers are blocked from producing, consumers can still consume.

> (4) If the producer's message will not be accepted by RabbitMQ, then is it possible to throw specific exception to the publisher from spring-cloud-stream (saying alarms are activated and message publish failed)?

Publishing is asynchronous by default; you can enable transactions (which can slow down performance a lot; or enable errors on the producer and you'll get an asynchronous message on the error channel if you enable publisher confirms and returns.